# Send data from ASP.NET MVC to desktop application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

What is the right and the simplest way to send some data (id/number) from asp.net mvc application to desktop application? I only need simplex communication. Webpage should initialize sending.

Comment: use MVC Web Api

Comment: asp.net mvc application should initialize sending

Comment: Azure WebJob then

Comment: Maybe look at SignalR. I don't  have experience with it myself but I understand it can be hosted in desktop apps too.

Comment: can you please describe task, which you want to resolve, it's not completely clear

Answer (score 0):

Create a HttpListner in your Windows forms application and post data to it from asp.net mvc
It's very simple

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listener = new HttpListener();
    listener.Prefixes.Add("http://localhost:8000/");
    listener.Prefixes.Add("http://127.0.0.1:8000/");
    listener.AuthenticationSchemes = AuthenticationSchemes.Anonymous;

    listener.Start();
    this.listenThread1 = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(startlistener));
    listenThread1.Start();
}
```

You can read the full article [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/599978/An-HttpListener-Server-for-Handling-AJAX-POST-Requ)